# nmap scan range of IPs, including localhost

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, nmap

I'm trying to scan my home network to see which elements of a set of devices (of which I have the MAC address) is currently connected to the network.

I'm using `nmap -n -sn -PR 192.168.0.0/24` as `root`, in order to obtain the connected hosts (especially the MAC addresses) and then filter out the result.

The weird thing is that for all the hosts I get (among other information) the MAC address, except for the IP corresponding to `localhost`.

The final script will probably run on some IoT device that will not be included in the list of required devices, so it's probably not gonna interfere, but I was wondering why `localhost` is treated differently.

Any suggestion?

**Clarification**

When I said "except for the IP corresponding to `localhost`" I meant "the IP that corresponds to the machine running the program", so a private one

Comment: Could it be that because localhost is not a NIC it has no manufacturer set MAC. (it is loopback, not physical).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question: nmap doesn't return the MAC address when it scans the IP which corresponds to the machine running the process, something like 192.168.0.100.